# Sencha Touch 2 App refuses to load content after a few days usage

Tags: javascript, ajax, caching, sencha-touch-2

First off, some context: we're building a sencha touch 2 app which works pretty well. It's basically a list with a panel which displays the content of an article that is currently tapped in the list. Kind of an RSS reader.

However, after using the app a couple of days, it turns out that it refuses to load content. Refreshing the page or reopening the app doesn't help - only manually clearing cache does.

Does anyone have a clue on how to solve this one? I obviously just clear all the elements in a given container when tapping a new item, so I wouldn't know what takes up so much cache...

Comment: Are you seeing an error, or does the app simply not load the new content? Are you using any cache busting strategies on your requests? It might help to look at some code.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any error. The list just doesn't load, which causes us to be unable to view any articles at all. I find it weird that it seems to relate to cache somehow, because it loads content perfectly otherwise... I also wouldn't know which bit of code you'd like to see, considering there's not much other than a simple model/store for these ajax requests :)

Comment: Doesn't it load the content or does he need more time to load it? I had the same problem with my rss feeds. My app loadad it 1 day after they were available online.

Comment: It just doesn't load any content at all. When we re-open the app, nothing is loaded at all (so the views are empty). This happens until we clear the cache.

Comment: It's tough to troubleshoot this without more information: Stepping through the code and watching the requests and responses is the best way forward.